# Accessing an instance variable from a method in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm having trouble accessing a variable from one method and get the error : EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

In MyClass.h I declared the var as such :

```
@interface ListeHorairesController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,   UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/*, NSXMLParserDelegate*/>
{
NSString *dateSelected;

...
```

Then in MyClass.m I try to use like so :

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style Donnees:(NSArray *)_data HeureDebut:(NSString *)_hDeb Date:(NSString *)_date
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self){
        dateSelected = _date;
        ...
```

Then in another method :

```
-(void)effectuerMajListes:(NSDictionary *)dictRes
{


    NSDateFormatter *formatter_now;
    NSString        *dateString;

    formatter_now = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter_now setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    dateString = [formatter_now stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [formatter_now release];

    //NSLog(@"%@", selected_date);

    if(![dateSelected isEqualToString:dateString]){ // <== ERROR POPS HERE

        NSLog(@"Not today : we won't refresh the view.");
        return;

    }
    ...
```

Can someone explain me why I've got this error, and how to do this properly?

Thanks.

I've tried using `self.dateSelected` `self->dateSelected` I've tried defining it as a class property, and using `@synthetize` onto it without success.

Comment: You should start with some memory managment tutorials - malloc, free, reference count, MRC, ARC... it's pretty important to know what those things mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using MRC, you need to retain the value.

The error shows that object does not exist.

Use :

```
dateSelected = [_date retain];
```

since `_date` is a parameter and you only assigned it to `darteSelected` and it(`_date`) got released in the end of method.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! I'll accept this answer when I can. Please tell me, to release it I'll have to use [_date release] at the end of the method right?

Comment: **NO** _date release is not required as you never alloc/retain/new/copied it. However in dealloc method you need to release dateSelected.

Comment: Also plz read memory management and now you have ARC, where all this are handled by compiler itself. then why  not to take advantage of this new feature, but *You must know the basic memory management.*

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely you're using manual memory management. Rather than fix this particular problem, you should use ARC (automatic retain counting) instead, which means you don't need to worry about these kinds of issues.

Comment: This is good idea, but MRC is must to know for at least till 2014. still many projects are running on MRC and you can't target for new projects.